# Is it possible to do sculpting on the objects generated by Geometric nodes (without applying the Geo modifier)?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, sculpt

The scene is from the Demo from the Blender Foundation:

[Cupcake](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/#geometry-nodes)

[image]
Before sculpting or adjusting the shape of the cream on the cake, I have to apply the Geometric modifier. But is it possible to sculpt it without applying the Geometric modifier please? Thank you!

I'd love to sculpt it by using Shape keys and the Multiresolution modifier. But it seems that I have to apply the Geometric modifier first.

Comment: It is not possible to do that (yet ?). You can however apply deformation modifiers without applying geometry nodes modifiers. Like Lattice, Mesh Deform, Armature, etc.

Comment: Your answer looks interesting! Could you please illustrate your meaning about "apply deformation modifiers without applying geometry nodes modifiers"? Are the deformation modifiers stacked above the geo modifiers or below it? Do deformation modifiers include the multiresolution modifier or not please?

Comment: Well sorry the phrasing was misleading, I didn't mean apply deformation modifiers but add them to the stack ,below the geometry nodes modifier. Note you'll have to add a "Realize Instances" node right before the geometry output if you're working with instances so the other modifiers can effect your object. I don't know anything about the multires so I can't answer, sorry. I guess you can test it pretty easily in your file though. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible without applying the Geo modifier?

Short answer: **No, definitely not**.

...and this will not change in the future.

Geometry Nodes are a modifier, and like any modifier, these only modify a mesh (or create one). However, this data is only ever actually converted into a mesh at the end of the chain (output/rendering).

For example, the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html) states:

*"They work by changing how an object is displayed and rendered, but not the geometry which you can edit directly."*

If you want to edit the result created by modifier as a mesh, you would have to apply the modifier.

Comment: Quote: "and this will not change in the future." In the next 10 years, I will always remember what you said. :D But so far, I am marking your answer correct.

Comment: @BlenderLake If that ever changed, then a new name would be created for it. And your task could possibly be solved if there was a *Sculpt Modifier*. The basic idea of a modifier is to change something in real time without changing the underlying data.

Comment: "Sculpt Modifier".... sounds a promising idea. But using the Shape keys when sculpting could also achieve something similar, right?

Comment: @BlenderLake Yes, *Sculpting* works on the same level as *Shape Keys*, and both have one thing in common: the topology of the mesh never changes! So it is always just a description of position changes and no new geometry is created. (Except for Remesh, but then a completely new geometry is created).